# Verificar permisos Acl dinámicamente en cakephp 4.x

Tags: cakephp, permisos

Tengo este código para verificar permisos con Acl en el archivo AppController.php en cakephp 4.x:

```
        $group_id = $this->Auth->user('group_id');
        if(!empty($group_id)){
            $this->group_id = $group_id;
            $group = $this->Groups->get($group_id);
            $checkACA1 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/add');
            $this->set('checkACA1', $checkACA1);
            $checkACA2 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/add', 'create');
            $this->set('checkACA2', $checkACA2);
            $checkACD1 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/delete');
            $this->set('checkACD1', $checkACD1);
            $checkACD2 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/delete', 'delete');
            $this->set('checkACD2', $checkACD2);
            $checkACE1 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/edit');
            $this->set('checkACE1', $checkACE1);
            $checkACE2 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/edit', 'update');
            $this->set('checkACE2', $checkACE2);
            $checkACI1 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/index');
            $this->set('checkACI1', $checkACI1);
            $checkACI2 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/index', 'create');
            $this->set('checkACI2', $checkACI2);
            $checkACI3 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/index', 'read');
            $this->set('checkACI3', $checkACI3);
            $checkACI4 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/index', 'update');
            $this->set('checkACI4', $checkACI4);
            $checkACI5 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/index', 'delete');
            $this->set('checkACI5', $checkACI5);
            $checkACV1 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/view');
            $this->set('checkACV1', $checkACV1);
            $checkACV2 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/view', 'create');
            $this->set('checkACV2', $checkACV2);
            $checkACV3 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/view', 'read');
            $this->set('checkACV3', $checkACV3);
            $checkACV4 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/view', 'update');
            $this->set('checkACV4', $checkACV4);
            $checkACV5 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'AffiliateCertificates/view', 'delete');
            $this->set('checkACV5', $checkACV5);
```

Aca solo puse un controller con sus acciones, pero el sitio tiene 17 controllers y cada controller tiene desde 3 actions o más, como pueden ver es muy largo y lo malo es que si agrego un controller y/o action nueva la tengo que agregar manualmente en el código, ¿hay alguna forma fácil de verificar los permisos dinámicamente sin tener que agregar más código?